# How to find all occurrences of a String on a page using Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

1. I want to find all occurrences of a string that exists on a Page (except the Page Footer). Should i use  `Element Should Contain  xpath://div[@id='post-page']   ${term}` ?
2. How to ignore case sensitivity for all the occurrences of the research term?(For example if i searched "term" and the page contains "Term" i want it to be on the result of occurrences )

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **Get WebElements** keyword from the [SeleniumLibrary](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20WebElements), this keyword will return you a list with all matching elements based on a locator.

To achieve what you are asking you just need to create the right locator, To find text in a non-case sensitive way there is a way not very "clean" to do it, see below:

```
/html/body//text()[   contains(     translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),     'term'   ) ]
```

In order to not apply this to the footer, just modify the beginning of the Xpath, the one above will find all the elements that contain the text term in a non-case sensitive way in the whole body